# NullPointerException while checking if array is empty

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, bukkit

I'm getting a NullPointerException when i'm checking if the length of the array is equal to 0 or not, and I can't find why it isn't working. Anyone could tell me what i'm doing wrong ?
Here's my entire function code:

```
    public static ArrayList<String> searchZone(Player p){
    openConnection();
    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    WorldEditPlugin worldEdit = (WorldEditPlugin) Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().getPlugin("WorldEdit");
    Selection selection = worldEdit.getSelection(p);
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + db + ".blocks";
    ArrayList<String> res = executeQueryWe(query);
    String[] items = res.toArray(new String[res.size()]);
    int i = 0;
    int iters = items.length;
    while(i < iters){
        try{
        if(selection != null){
            String[] locs = items[i].split(",");
            World world = Bukkit.getServer().getWorld(locs[0]);
            int x = Integer.valueOf(locs[1]);
            int y = Integer.valueOf(locs[2]);
            int z = Integer.valueOf(locs[3]);
            Location loc = new Location(world, x, y ,z);
            if(selection.contains(loc)){

                String query2 = "SELECT * FROM `blocks` WHERE `world`='" + world.getName() + "' AND `x`='" + x + "' AND `y`='" + y + "' AND `z`='" + z + "';";
                data = executeQuery(query2);
            }
        }
        } catch(Exception e){
            closeConnection();
            p.sendMessage(prefix + ChatColor.RED + "An error occured while reading database");
            break;
        }
        p.sendMessage(prefix + ChatColor.RED + "Please make a selection first");
        break;
    }
    if(data.size() != 0){ //<---------------------------- ERROR COMES FROM HERE
        closeConnection();
        return data;
    } else {
        data.add("No entries has been found.");
        closeConnection();
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: This suggests to me that `executeQuery(query2)` is returning `null`. I'd check this if I were you, and if it's true, you will need to do some sleuthing to find out why.

Comment: To Elaborate on what @HovercraftFullOfEels is saying. Because executeQuery is returning null you are not able to call `.size()` because data is not an arraylist it is null. If you make sure that data is not NULL then this test will work, otherwise change the test to  see if data itself is null

Comment: True, but even with `if(!data.equals(null) || !data.isEmpty() || data.size() != 0){` it gives me a nullPointerException

Comment: Aw chit, you **never** check for null using `if (foo.equals(null))` as that will always fail since you'll be calling a method on a null. Again **never** do this. You **always** use `if (foo == null)` or `if (foo != null)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'data' variable may be null since even though you are initializing it in the beginning, you set it again further down. Check data for null

`if(data != null && data.size() != 0)`

Comment: Now i'm getting a NullPointerException on `data.add("No entries has been found.");`

Comment: @davidp027 Right. Because `data` is `null`, which is one of the 5 listed reasons [why you get these exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html). So use what you learned here and apply it to other situations.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting `NullPointerException` because `executeQuery(query2)` might return `null` if no matching record for the location is available.

One way to solve is, Check for `null` and then `size`.

```
data != null && !data.isEmpty()
```

This does the same function as your code but without using `0` literal.

another way is to add, [apache collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.util.Collection%29) to your project and do it with

```
CollectionUtils.isEmpty(<your list here>);
```

This is `null` safe and will return `true` if your arraylist is either `null` or `empty`.